# How to validate a form in Kohana 3.3.1

Tags: validation, kohana

I'm trying to validate a form but it doesn't show validation errors and if field is empty, it saves. How to validate form?
My code is:

```
public function action_upload()
{
 if($_POST) {

                $name = array(
                    'name' => Arr::get($_POST, 'name')
                );
                $validate = Validation::factory($name)
                ->rule('name', 'not_empty');
               try {  

                    $save = Model_Offers::Save($this->user['user_id'],  $name);

                }
                catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
                {
                    $result = $e->errors('models');
                    echo '<pre>';
                    print_r($result);
                    exit;
                }

            }

    }
```

My view is:

```html
<form id="myForm" action="<?php echo URL::base()?>user/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="input-group">
    <label for="file">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Haven't worked with Kohana for some time, but shouldn't it be `->rule('title', 'not_empty');`? You are setting the key to `title`, not `name`

Comment: It is about `name` input.

Comment: Yes, but there is no `$title['name']`, only `$title['title']`

Comment: Yes, it's when writing it in question, I'll edit it.

Comment: I did it in JS, but I Kohana is still difficult for me.

Comment: The issue is still the same. You are assigning the key `title` (line 6), but in the validation add a rule for key `name` (line 9)

Comment: and it is still not working? Do you get any error message?

Comment: I did it using Javascript. Kohana is still difficult for me.

Answer (score 0):

You created the validation object, but you forgot to actually apply the rules you assigned. Simply do this by calling

```
$validate->check()
```

It'd be best to put this in an if-else statement

```
if($validate->check()){
//Save object
}
else{
//Get errors (use $validate->errors())
}
```

Hope that helps! :)